# Virtual Box Router - Windows Host, Linux Guest

Tags: windows, ubuntu, router, dhcp, bridge

I currently have Ubuntu Server running as the Guest OS in Virtual Box on a Windows 7 Host.

The Ubuntu Server gets its IP from DHCP and is Bridged to the my Network Adapter.

I've disabled Internet access for my Windows Host, and my Guest OS has no problem getting an IP.

I need to add a second adapter in my Windows Host that will connect to Guest OS and get an IP via DHCP from whatever connection my Guest OS is connected to. I don't know if this can be accomplished with a "Host Only Adapter" or "Loopback Adapter" somehow or not.

Alternatively, I just need to forward certain ports on my Guest to my Host and be able to communicate back and forth through the Guest OS with the outside world.

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can confirgure port forwarding in virtualbox. (You have to set networking mode to NAT)

Here is the link on how to do it:

http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#natforward